# Capturar excepción de Guzzle 6.3 en laravel: Object of class GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response could not be converted to string

Tags: laravel-5, webservice, guzzle

Estoy implementando el siguiente código en laravel para consumir un servicio web, funciona perfecto cuando la respuesta es 200, pero en el caso de ser 500 intento atrapar la excepción pero produce error:

```
use GuzzleHttp; //En cabecera

public function consumir_servicio()
{
    $url = 'http://xxx.xxx.x.xx/api/miapi/';
    $cliente = new GuzzleHttp\Client(['base_uri' =>$url]);
    try {
        $resultado = $cliente->request('post');
    } 
   catch(GuzzleHttp\Exception\ServerException $e) { //Produce error
        dd($e);
    }
}
```

Este es el error:

> Object of class GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response could not be converted to string

Comment: ¿Qué versión de Guzzle está utilizando?

Comment: La version 6.3 olvide indicarlo

Comment: Debe obtener el response de la excepción `$e->getResponse()->getBody()->getContents()` es por eso que no puede hacer la conversión. Pero que desea hacer con la excepción? desea hacer alguna tarea dependiendo de la excepción o que exactamente.

Comment: Si quiero mostrar el error, lo conseguí con esta sintaxis: Psr7\str($e->getResponse());